# LeapMotion Java Example - Adding External Library

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, leap-motion

I am trying to make a java program to see it leapmotion libraries are working with Java.
I work on Eclipse (however, it didn't worked on NetBeans as well.) I created my project. Then created a subfolder named "libs" and put "LeapJava.jar" into it. An under libs folder there is a "armeabi" folder and "libLeapJava.so" and "libLeap.so" files in it. Under project properties > java build path I added LeapJava.jar as library and in my source file I did

```
static {
System.loadLibrary("LeapJava");
}
```

It didn't work for me. I still get

```
Native code library failed to load. 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no LeapJava in java.library.path
```

These are all I tried. Can you help me with solving this problem please?

Comment: https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/java/devguide/Project_Setup.html

Answer (score 0):

https://community.leapmotion.com/t/java-development-no-leapjava-in-java-library-path/315/5

I met with the same problem and I followed the tip from the above website:

> I faced the same problem and I copied all the files from LeapMotionSDK/lib/x64 to the root directory of my netbeans project. This solved the problem.
>
> So my solution is add those files to your classpath.
>
> I am on Windows 8.1 and using netbeans IDE. Running on 64bit JRE.

It works for me and I hope that could help you.